# containsAll for nCopies of object in List

Tags: java, list, collections, contains

I would like to check if an Arraylist contains n copies of the same element.
Here's the problem:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class testMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        myClass myObject = new myClass("haha1");

        ArrayList a = new ArrayList();
        a.add(myObject);
        a.add(new myClass("haha2"));
        a.add(new myClass("haha3"));

        List b;
        b = Collections.nCopies(5, myObject);
        System.out.println(a.containsAll(b)); //prints true
    }

    static private class myClass {
        String a;

        myClass(String a) {
            this.a = a;
        }
    }
}
```

Problem 1: List `b` has a greater size than list `a` - should be false
Problem 2: List `b` has more than one `myObject` objects (as opposed to List`a` - should be false

This doesn't work due to the way containsAll works, since I want to see if the object `myObject` is contained (in this case) *3 times* in List `a`.

I know I can write my own method that would do exactly what I want, but I was wondering if there is an out of the box solution for this case or what would be the most "elegant" way of handling it.

EDIT: Removed clarification for my use of `myClass` as it was conflicting with given example.

Comment: “*I should clarify that in my case `myClass` is enum.*”—given the multiple occurrences of `new myClass(…)` in your code, *no*, it is not. Not to speak of the included declaration.

Comment: @Holger I've used myClass to illustrate the problem and I can see how it can be confusing when I mention enum in this case. I've removed it in order to not further confuse someone.

Comment: You didn’t remove it, you added another statement…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Collections.frequency(a,myObject) == 5` (or `Collections.frequency(a,myObject) >= 5` if you don't mind if your `Collection` has more than 5 instances pf `myObject`).

> **int java.util.Collections.frequency(Collection c, Object o)**
>
> Returns the number of elements in the specified collection equal to the specified object. More formally, returns the number of elements e in the collection such that (o == null ? e == null : o.equals(e)).